# How to initially select a cell of a tktable?

Tags: python, tkinter, tktable

I am using Python `tktable` (**not** `tkintertable`) for making a table with `tkinter`.

Now my problem is: I want the cell(s) from table to be selected initially. For example, when I open the GUI, cell `row=1, col=1` will be auto selected.

I checked the [tcl tktable manual](http://www.tcl.tk/community/hobbs/tcl/capp/tkTable/tkTable.html), but no luck.

So, how to do this?

Comment: What does "no luck" mean? The documentation clearly shows how to select one or more cells.

Comment: Maybe I missed that, can you please provide the code or keyword argument that I have to passed

Comment: look for the widget command `selection`. You can use it to get and set the selected cells.

Comment: Well I found the command `selection_set()` but it only select a single or between a range. I can selecte only say the two cell 1,2 and 1,5 . it will select 4 cell instead of two but still it is okay enough for my job. Thanks

Comment: @BryanOakley Could you please give an answer then?